# Issues with syslog on Raspbian using gnu c++ 11

Tags: c, c++11, raspberry-pi3, raspbian, syslog

Ok so I am having problems with syslog on Raspbian Stretch.  I am trying to write to /var/log/blah.log using local0 as my facility.  I am using gnu C++ 11 As the application is being written in C++ so I trying to create a logging class.

My /etc/syslog.conf has the following entry

```
local0.*    /var/log/blah.log
```

... and I have restarted the service and the Pi.

My code to open the log is as follows:

```
setlogmask(LOG_UPTO(LOG_DEBUG));
openlog(blah, LOG_PERROR | LOG_CONS | LOG_NDELAY, LOG_LOCAL0);
```

...and my logging code is:

```
syslog(LOG_INFO | LOG_LOCAL0, fullMessage.c_str());
```

There is no /var/log/blah.log file created and no log entries written, although the message is written to the console as I am using LOG_CONS.

If I replace LOG_LOCAL0 with LOG_USER I am successfully able write to user.log.

I do want to be able to write to the custom log file because:
a) it is easy to ask a user to look at that file for debugging purposes
b) it should work!!

As I have stated I have looked through the numerous posts on this site and others and still cannot get it top work so posting links to man pages and other articles won't help!

Comment: I don't think there's anything wrong with your code.  This smells like a problem with the syslog daemon itself.  Is it possible that the version of syslogd that ships with Raspbian doesn't support the localN facilities?

Comment: Good question... I will ask Google again

Comment: thanks to all the people who have reviewed the question for grammatical and syntactical correctness.  I don´t wish to sound rude, but if you are not going to bother answering the question then don´t bother suggesting corrections.  If you are unable to understand any of the content then please ask